# Trouble Showing a Complex Identity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but not sure how to continue.

> Let $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ where $z \mapsto 1/(1-z)$. If $\phi = \arg z$ and $r=|z|$, show 
>   $$ f(z) = \left[ \frac{1-r\cos\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos\phi} \right] + i\left[ \frac{r\sin\phi}{1+r^2-2r\cos\phi} \right]. $$

First I rewrote $f$,

$$ f(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z^2}. $$

Then I substituted $z\mapsto re^{i\phi}$ and tried to show the above expression,

\begin{align*}
  f(re^{i\phi}) &= \frac{1+re^{i\phi}}{1-\left(re^{i\phi}\right)^2} \\
  &= \frac{1 + r\cos\phi + ri\sin\phi}{1-r^2(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)^2} \\
\end{align*}

Let $L = 1-r^2(\cos\phi + i\sin\phi)^2$ for the moment.

$$ f(z) = \frac{1+r\cos\phi}{L} + i\frac{r\sin\phi}{L} $$

which is close to the numerators of the original identity, apart from the sign of $r\cos\phi$. Now for $L$,

$$ L = 1 - r^2(\cos^2\phi + 2i\cos\phi\sin\phi - \sin^2\phi) $$

This could be rewritten with double angle formulas as $1-r^2(\cos2\phi + i\sin2\phi)$, but I could've easily gotten that from writing $r^2e^{2i\phi}$ earlier and I also don't see how it helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the complex conjugate $z^*$ to write $$f(z) = \frac{1-z^*}{(1-z^*)(1-z)} = \frac{1-z^*}{1- 2 |z| \cos \phi + |z|^2}$$
Then you're done, writing $z^* = |z| \cos \phi -  i |z| \sin \phi$ and $|z| =r$.

Comment: is there a way of showing this via the route I was taking? or was that incorrect?